# xcode 4.2 storyboard, segue by code

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to make the segue between a button created by coding and a view created in storyboard?

(the button is not in the storyboard, it's made inside the viewcontroller .m class)

please help if you know the solution
thanks,

Answer (score 9):

If the current view controller (the one that owns the button) came from the storyboard, you can just use the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method of `UIViewController`, like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:sender];
```